# How to backup/restore SQLite database in React native

Tags: sqlite, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using [andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) for managing SQLite database in React native. Now I want to backup all my database into a encrypted file then restore this at later time. I know how to do this in android but don't know how to implement this in react native.

if it is in android below code can help me to backup the database without encryption.

```
 final String inFileName = "/data/data/<your.app.package>/databases/foo.db";
File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/database_copy.db";

// Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

// Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0){
    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

// Close the streams
output.flush();
output.close();
fis.close();
```

So my question is how I can do this on React Native. If there any libraries available please suggest to me.

Answer (score 4):

Same approach can be followed in react-native too using [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs) package.

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

RNFS.readFile("/data/data/<your.app.package>/databases/foo.db", "base64")
    .then(value => RNFS
        .getAllExternalFilesDirs()
        .then(path => RNFS.writeFile(path + "/" + "database_copy.db", value, "base64"))
        .then(() => console.log("Successful"))
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

```
import DocPicker from 'react-native-document-picker'
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'

async function restoreDB() {
    try {
        const rsPicker = await DocPicker.pickSingle()
        const filePath = rsPicker.uri
        await RNFS.copyFile(filePath, '/data/data/<your.app.package>/databases/foo.db')
        msgInfo('Success Restore Database');

    } catch (e) {
        msgError(e)
    }
}

async function backupDB() {
    try {
        const currDate = format(new Date(), 'dd_MM_yyyy_HHmmss')
        const destPath = RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + 'foo_' + currDate + '.db'
        await RNFS.copyFile('/data/data/<your.app.package>/databases/foo.db',
            destPath)
        msgInfo('Success Backup Database');
    } catch (e) {
        msgError(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).